# Pivot data in mapping dataflows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to pivot the values into description using mapping dataflows
My example
So the value column plots to each new description value column.

it should look like this
[image]

I understand that the groupings will be on the IDName, ID and DateTime columns and I have removed the columns I don't need.

I'd like to know what goes where in the pivot values
[image]

Thanks

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the PivotKey will be 'Description' and the Pivoted Columns should be something like 'max(Value)'.

Comment: Yes, I eventually worked it out and got it working. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1:** Create dataflow

[image]

**Step2:** Add original dataset to source

[image]

**Step3:** In Pivot Settings use groupby on ID, IDName, DateTime columns

[image]

You will get data preview as expected

[image]

**Step4:** Then Configure Sink with output csv and Store data to target file.

[image]